# Delphi for windows and linux

Tags: windows, linux, delphi

I'm developing some software in Delphi (RFID) that sooner or later would want to run in Linux, what good option can I use so I don't have to do it from zero?
I've seen the Embarcadero option but is not free!

thank you!

Comment: Be prepared that if you use external DLLs in your solution, that you need to make sure you make those run on Linux too.

Comment: Apparently a Linux and Mac OS version of delphi is in development, due for release some time mid 2011. not sure about actual dates though.

Comment: Delphi and lazarus won't help you with the fundamental problem that the USB access APis of Windows and Linux are DIFFERENT. Also you will need device drivers for both platforms. Assume you have those already?

Comment: He didn't mention that his RFID reader is USB based, and even if it is I don't think that he would plan his future development on linux if his RFID reader does not have linux driver. He also didn't mention that he is an embedded developer so I will not presume that he will write his own linux USB drivers. And even if it is such a case, there is cross platform libusb library that he can use. I will also note that some RFID readers are HID USB compliants which means that drivers are not needed since HID is supported in all major OS by default (otherwise USB mouse and keyboard would not work).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although I agree that Lazarus/FreePascal is the way to go, cross compilation can be a real pain to setup properly. Therefore, you could take a look at free [CodeTyphon](http://www.pilotlogic.com/sitejoom/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=96&catid=68&Itemid=147). It is a powerful one click installation package for cross platform native Delphi like RAD/IDE based on Lazarus/FreePascal. You can start coding just few minutes after the download. CodeTyphon already supports 4 CPU/OS hosts (Win32, Win64, Linux32, Linux64), and 16 CPU/OS targets (arm-WinCE, arm-Linux, arm-Embedded, arm-gba, arm-nds, i386-Win32, i386-Linux, i386-FreeBSD, i386-Haiku, x86_64-Win64, x86_64-Linux, x86_64-FreeBSD, powerpc-Linux, powerpc64-Linux, sparc-Linux, sparc-Solaris). More platforms are supported in Lazarus/FreePascal, but others are not yet integrated in CodeTyphon.

Answer (score 5):

If you are set on Delphi and don't want to use [Free Pascal](http://freepascal.org/) then you can use [Wine](http://www.winehq.org) on the Linux side to run your Win32 app.

Comment: hi, thank you, I would like to avoid wine, because is intended for the beagle board which is not very powerful (embedded Linux), I have to see if it could handle it..

Comment: What ISA does this beagle board run? Remember that Delphi currently only targets x86.

Comment: The beagle board runs a TI OMAP 3 Chip afaik. So it's an ARM architecture... Delphi won't compile for this, and Wine is most likely not available, too. FPC/Larazus could work though...

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Lazarus](http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/) which is free IDE for developing cross platform application using Free Pascal which emulates Delphi.

For more information go through [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazarus_%28software%29)

Comment: thanks I would try it, how would the USB behave? very different from Delphi implementation? as I intend to use the software to read/write   RFID USB cards

Comment: Is there such thing as "Delphi USB implementation"? What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 3):

If you've got a Delphi 7 license, you'd also have Kylix 3.
You can still cross-compile from Delphi to Linux using [the great CrossKylix](http://crosskylix.untergrund.net): debug in Windows, then cross-compile it for Linux, with the same compiler version. I'm still using this on production. Great solution for writting not GUI software (e.g. a server hosted in [a cheap Linux box](http://www.online.net/serveur-dedie/offre-dedibox-v3.xhtml)).

If your target is some kind of embedded platform (that's what your comments suggest), I'd recommend using [FreePascal](http://freepascal.org) which target x86, and also ARM. Without Lazarus as UI layer, but something lighter, like [fpGui](http://wiki.freepascal.org/fpGUI) or [MSEIde/MSEGui](http://www.msegui.org).